# Can't add ads to my app.

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, banner

So I followed this guide from admob with Google Play Services, https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play
And I have encountered a problem.
The code they provided on their website is not working.I get errors.

```
    package puske.com;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Menu extends Activity {
private AdView adView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    // Create the adView.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout".
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuz);

    // Add the adView to it.
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Load the adView with the ad request.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I get error on `adView = new AdView(this);` the Constructor AdView(Menu) is undefined.

```
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER); the Method setAdSize is undefined for the type AdView
```

And `adView.loadAd(adRequest);`
The method load.ad(adRequest) in the type AdView is not applicable for the arguments (AdRequest)

I added https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=en_US as said in guide, and still doesn't work. http://prntscr.com/2o6vo4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use layout to show your add. Just put below code in your layout where ever you want into the screen.

```
     <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="Your AddMob ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE" />  
    </RelativeLayout>
```

You should have the newest GoogleAdmobSdk.jar in you libs folder.
This is working for me.

Comment: so we need refer to this xml add element in java file ? @Deeepak Jangir

Comment: You only need to add this in layout xml file.

Comment: google play services has some different implementation and it does not support load on create

Answer (score 2):

Try to add directly at the import area the following lines

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

If you are migrating to new way of use addMob don`t forget to remove the old library.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

EDIT:

Remove

```
setContentView(R.layout.menu);
```

add behind loadAd()

```
setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: I still get error The Method load.ad(adRequest) in the type AdView is not applicable for the arguments(AdRequests)

Answer (score 0):

Remove any other ad sdk(in my case it was adfonic) from your project as there is a conflict and try. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

AND adding following into layout:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="Your AddMob ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE" />
```

works