# Android Adding AdView into HTML5WebView

Tags: android, webview, admob, adview

I am using HTML5WebView.

https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FHTML5WebView%253Fstate%253Dclosed

I am adding Google AdView at the bottom of the HTML5WebView but AdView is showing over on top of the HTML5WebView. I would like HTML5WebView take only the rest of the screen after AdView is taken.

May I know how can I change my layout. I have tried so may way but no luck. Here is my latest result that AdView is overlapping HTML5WebView.

Thanks,
Alex

Here is my

custom_screen.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >        
        <ProgressBar 
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:indeterminate="true"
               android:id="@+id/webViewProgressBar"/>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/error_console"
            android:orientation="vertical"          
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />          
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView          
             android:id="@+id/adView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             ads:adUnitId="a15302d1a9e05e7"
             ads:adSize="BANNER"
             ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
             ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

HTML5WebView.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

    private Context                                                         mContext;
    private MyWebChromeClient                                               mWebChromeClient;
    private View                                                            mCustomView;
    private FrameLayout                                                     mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback                              mCustomViewCallback;

    private FrameLayout                                                     mContentView;
    private FrameLayout                                                     mBrowserFrameLayout;
    private FrameLayout                                                     mLayout;
    private ProgressBar                                                     progressBar;
static final String LOGTAG = "HTML5WebView";

    @SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "SdCardPath" })
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;             
        Activity a = (Activity) mContext;

        mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

        mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.custom_screen, null);
        mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

        mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.webViewProgressBar);
        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

        setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(progressBar));

        // Configure the webview
        WebSettings s = getSettings();
        s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        s.setSavePassword(true);
        s.setSaveFormData(true);
        s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // enable navigator.geolocation 
        s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        s.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/org.itri.html5webview/databases/");

        // enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
        s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mContentView.addView(this);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(context);
    }

    public FrameLayout getLayout() {
            return mLayout;
    }

public boolean inCustomView() {
            return (mCustomView != null);
    }

public void hideCustomView() {
            mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()){
                    goBack();
                    return true;
            }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap          mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View            mVideoProgressView;   


        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
        {
                //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on ShowCustomView");
            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {

                if (mCustomView == null)
                        return;        

                // Hide the custom view.
                mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Remove the custom view from its container.
                mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
                mCustomView = null;
                mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

                HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Log.i(LOGTAG, "set it to webVew");
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
                //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on getDefaultVideoPoster");    
                if (mDefaultVideoPoster == null) {
                        mDefaultVideoPoster = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                        getResources(), R.drawable.default_video_poster);
            }
                return mDefaultVideoPoster;
        }

        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {
                //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on getVideoLoadingPregressView");

        if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);
        }
        return mVideoProgressView; 
        }

         @Override
         public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            ((Activity) mContext).setTitle(title);
         }

         @Override
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                 ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, newProgress*100);
         }

         @Override
         public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
             callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
         }
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        public MyWebViewClient(ProgressBar progressBar) {
            this.progressBar=progressBar;
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             super.onPageFinished(view, url); 

             progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: "+url);
            // don't override URL so that stuff within iframe can work properly
            // view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }      

    }

    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS =
    new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479203/cant-ad-ads-to-my-app/21479521#21479521

Comment: Hi Deepak,thanks for the link. My problem is that Adview is overlapping HTMLWebView. I think that it is because of the HTMLWebView layout. Now footer of my web page is overlapping by AdView. So that user can't click some link on footer. I have tried the example from above link but the result is the same.

Comment: hi, alex.can you solve this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812917/not-enough-ad-space-when-add-admob-in-html5webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your LinearLayout and AdView like so:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >        

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >        
        <ProgressBar 
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:indeterminate="true"
               android:id="@+id/webViewProgressBar"/>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/error_console"
            android:orientation="vertical"          
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />          
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView          
             android:id="@+id/adView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             ads:adUnitId="a15302d1a9e05e7"
             ads:adSize="BANNER"
             ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
             ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi William, thanks you so much. It is exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: how about this sir?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812917/not-enough-ad-space-when-add-admob-in-html5webview